# Selecting text and image from pdf through any programming language

Tags: pdf, web-applications, programming-languages, selection

I'm trying to develop a tool/web application such that it will import a PDF file and I need to select text and images available in PDF by selecting them with a mouse click and marking them as title,content and image with a button click (3 different button) where the marked contents and image will be copied to clipboard or will be pasted into a word document which is going to be a another part. So in which programming language is this possible to work with and carry on ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try researching pure browser-side solution using [`pdf.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) and [clipboard API](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/).

Otherwise, you'd still need `clipboard API` in the browser and the server-side may actually be powered by any programming language which can be hooked into a web server and has a library to parse PDFs.

You said nothing at all about your prospective server platform but to name a few, .NET has [PdfSharp](https://github.com/DavidS/PdfTextract) which is able to read PDFs, [Python has a host of tools](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167) available for it. After all, there exist a bunch of command-line utilities to extract data from PDF which can be called using any PL able to call external processes.

Note that this only *appears* to be a simpler solution than using `pdf.js` but note that unless your PDFs are really uniform (say, invoices created by some piece of software), and so you'll be able to make your PDF parser *know* which bits of data it has to extract and return, the parser will need to returl all the data it extracted to the client, and you'll need to somehow render it all there.  May be it's exactly what you need but maybe not.

Since PDFs are really tailored for typesetting and not presenting information in a structured manner, I'd try to piggyback on an already hard-core PDF rendering solution which runs in the browser, so see above.

Comment: is it possible to render images too ?